# Low level HTTP filtering for Windows

Tags: c#, windows, http, winapi, fiddler

I would like to implement a parental control for *all* browsers in Windows. I am thinking in a .NET application.

My first thought was create a local HTTP proxy (like Fiddler), even use Fiddlers embeddable API. However this proxy easily can be workarounded even by a kid, just (re) setting the browsers not to use this local proxy.

So I've concluded I have to go deeper.
My question, am I right? ...and how and where...

Thanks in advance

Comment: See here for some open source solutions that may get you started: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls

Comment: And here http://blog.opendns.com/2010/06/23/introducing-familyshield-parental-controls/

Comment: I think your recommendations not for Windows. About OpenDNS and similar I think (re) setting a DNS back is not a hard task for a kid. They a more clever we think. They will Google for it how to do that. And to be clear: I am not searching for a parental control solution, I am asking for help, how to do it in _Windows_ using .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "official" way to do this would be to build a filter atop the Windows Filtering Platform; it's designed for this sort of thing, and it's how Windows' own Parental Controls feature is built.

Having said that, you *can* build a Parental Controls application using FiddlerCore. You would then use Group Policy to control proxy settings (Create a REG_DWORD named `ProxySettingsPerUser` with value `0` inside `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings\`) such that the settings cannot be changed by non-administrative users.

You could further bolster this by applying Firewall policies such that direct egress is blocked and only traffic going through Fiddler is permitted to leave the box.

Comment: Hi Eric. Thanks for the official answer. And thanks for your hints to use FiddelerCore. Secretly I hoped I can use Fiddler :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to do it with .NET. If you want to see all HTTP traffic regardless of the browser settings, you'll need to either hook into every process and override calls to the sockets API, or get into the network driver layer and see the communications there.

.NET is wrong for both - you don't want to attach a .NET DLL to non-.NET processes, and you don't want to create a .NET driver.

You'll also need to somehow override the DNS, because otherwise you'll have no way to prevent HTTPS access - you can't monitor HTTPS, you can only prevent it.